# Third Party Tracing Tools for Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Apart from Sql server profiler ,is there any third party user friendly tool available to
trace sql server objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it's not free, what about the [SQL Trace Analyser](http://www.sqlsolutions.com/products/sql-trace-analyzer/). But I prefer the MS SQL Profiler over all free products on the market. The [SQL 2008 Developer version](http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/SQL-Server-2008-Developer-Edition/product/C5EA00C9?WT.mc_id=productinfocenter) costs $ 49.95.